# Does viewing own profile count to profile views?

Tags: support, profile-page, views

I have not seen an answer to this in other questions.

So, if I visit my own page over and over with an interval of, let's say, 60 min. will my profile views counter grow?

Is the counter for unique views only?

Comment: even if a duplicate, it wasn't answered. Would be great to see some definitive answers.

Comment: @CreativeMagic As per my notice, it doesnt count self profile viewing. However I may be wrong. I have check this many time before my SO profile's count cross 0.

Comment: Yeah, it's hard to understand. Sometimes refreshing my own profile I see a new view, but I can't know if it's from me or not. Thing is, if I refresh after 20 min, I see another view! And that's when I didn't answer/asked questions for a week or so. Makes me wonder. So...I just want to know the official answer.

Comment: You definitely should =) I mean who want's to spend their own rep with no chance of getting it back :D